# Tkinter - code structure, construction and organisation - application append sub-frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a tkinter application that automatically creates independent sub-frames. I know a little on tkinter code, so I can create myself all these `Combobox`, `Button`, and other simple things. I just need some help on the principal construction of structure, the classes and functions, callback functions.

[image: diagram of widget layout]

There is a little description how you can use the application:

Set `combobox1`, next set `combobox2` that depend of the choice in `combobox1` (I know how to do that).
When you click on the `+` button in the `TopFrame`, this append a `FrameX` in the 'invisible' `GroupOfFrame` area (maybe this `GroupOfFrame` frame is not necessary).

In a single sub-frame `FrameX`, set `combobox3` with values that depend of the `combobox2` and `combobox1` selections. Next you can press a button (`button2.X`) that will execute some code that use the selection of the 3 comboboxes (1, 2, and 3.X) (and some entries in the same sub-frame).

Every sub-frame need to be indepedent, but all the `button2.X` call the same function that use the `combobox3.X` related (I do not know how to do that).

You can click on the `-` button that will remove the single sub-frame related and drag up all the others sub-frames under.

If possible, the main button `button1` run all the others `button2.X`.
You can add or remove sub-frames as much as you want.

The purpose is that I do not know how to organise my code.
I hope this description is understandable.

I do not put any code because I don't know how to begin this project (sorry). I tried some things but these did not fit. I do not necessary want full code example.

Comment: You should probably look for some tkinter tutorials.

Comment: How good are you with classes? Have you tried making the `TopFrame` into it's own class? What data structures are you going to use in your program? Can you please show us your best attempt?

Comment: There is no tutorial for that on internet.
I do not want to open a TopFrame on top of the main Frame application, I want everything in the same frame if possible. I will make some code again and put it next

Comment: @RamboSushi Putting everything in the same frame will be very difficult. `Frame`s were designed to split your GUI into multiple parts. That makes coding each part much easier. If each part is it's own class then creating/debugging it should become much easier

Comment: @TheLizzard Okay I will try to use more TopFrame. But I am not this good with classes.

Comment: @RamboSushi Your project looks quite big. It will be very hard to do without classes. Try looking at [this](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).

Comment: @TheLizzard The thing that I do not know is, in a class App(tk.Frame), in one of it fucntion, you can call another class Frame(tk.Frame), and keep the posibilities to come back in the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create two classes. Think of the first class as a custom widget that behaves much like a notebook. The main difference is that instead of tabs you have a vertical stack of frames. It creates the widgets in `TopFrame` from your drawing, and it has methods for adding and deleting the frames in the bottom section.

The second class represents one "tab" or one frame/combo/entry/button group. It is responsible for creating itself, and is given a reference to the first class in order to delete itself and do other things.

I've included some example code to get you started. It doesn't add the comboboxes in the top frame since I think it's somewhat irrelevant to the overall structure of the code which is what you're asking about.

In the following code, `FrameStack` is the first class. It creates `TopFrame` and `GroupOfFrames` from your diagram, and adds functions for adding and removing frames.

`SubFrame` represents the combination of a combobox, entry widget, a big button and a small button. Notice how the minus button calls back to the `delete_frame` method of the first class.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class FrameStack(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.subframes = []
        self.topFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.groupOfFrames = tk.Frame(self, height=200)
        self.topFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.groupOfFrames.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.add = tk.Button(self.topFrame, text="+", command=self.add_frame)
        self.add.pack(side="right")

    def delete_frame(self, frame):
        self.subframes.remove(frame)
        frame.destroy()

    def add_frame(self):
        f = SubFrame(parent=self.groupOfFrames, controller=self)
        self.subframes.append(f)
        f.pack(side="top", fill="x")

class SubFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller

        self.cb = ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.main_button = tk.Button(self, width=10)
        self.remove_button = tk.Button(self, text="-", command=self.remove)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.cb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.main_button.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.remove_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="se")

    def remove(self):
        self.controller.delete_frame(self)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

fs = FrameStack(root)
fs.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```